# Numbering all rows by an order

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a two column PK.  I'd like to add a new column, `nid`, which numbers each row (1,2,3...), based on a particular ORDER BY.

So:

```
x | y | z
3   7   2
1   4   1
```

When numbered by z ASC becomes:

```
x | y | z | nid
3   7   2 | 2
1   4   1 | 1
```

Can I do this in SQL (Postgres 9.4)?

Comment: what if there were duplicates in z column?

Comment: Which particular ORDER BY?

Comment: How should the database behave when you add a row somewhere else than at the end of this order? Should it update every row further in this order to increase its number by one? Looks like a hassle... I'm not a DBA but I think you'd better get this number request by request or create a view that computes it when needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can just use `row_number()`:

```
select x, y, z, row_number() over (order by z) as nid
from t;
```